# Getting the number of touch points supported

Tags: android, multi-touch

I know that the number of touch points supported is different from device to device, but is there a way through the API or through code to get that number for the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can distinguish between various broad classes of multitouch (none, pinch gestures only, true 2-point multitouch, true 5-point multitouch) by searching the result of [PackageManager#getSystemAvailableFeatures()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getSystemAvailableFeatures%28%29) for the various "android.hardware.touchscreen.*" features listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features).

If you want to know exactly how many touches may be present, you'll just have to watch MotionEvents as they come in.