# Which Android devices/version combinations do / do not support multitouch gestures in the browser?

Tags: android, browser, cross-browser, gestures, multi-touch

I'm implementing the possibility to use multi-touch in openLayers in an Android app even for Android versions that do not support browser multi-touch. Therefore, I need to distinguish between those devices/Android versions that support and those that don't. I need this information to apply a hack to distinguish what functionality to provide to the respecitve devices.

Does there exist a list of devices/versions mentioning multi-touch support? Or is there a method to detect browser multi-touch support during runtime (without explicit user interaction)?

Answer (score 1):

To re-enable multitouch on your applications' WebView with 2.x devices you can include [WebView MultiTouch Polyfill](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill/) in your project.

To elaborate the question you are asking i have started this "RFC-alike" entry in order to [detect how many touches are available to the webview](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill/issues/9). The approach i have described there is an unproven concept and would be my last-resort implementation in case [this kind of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067941/getting-the-number-of-touch-points-supported) is not available on the webview.

Would love to get some comments or clarification and also hope, this may somehow help you.

Answer (score 0):

About the closest I've seen would be PPK's tables [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html).