# How many fingers touch can be handle simultaneously in android os?

Tags: android, operating-system, touch

I want to handle touch event of five finger simultaneously on an android tablet. How can I do?
Thanks for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067941/getting-the-number-of-touch-points-supported

Answer (score 3):

This is different per device. You have to test this functionality by using the Touch APIs that are available.

Answer (score 0):

Usually - 10, depends on device and drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MotionEvent.getPointerId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId(int)) and [MotionEvent.getPointerCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount()) to handle multi-touch events.